# Isohedron splitting into isohedra

Tags: recreational-mathematics, polyhedra, solid-geometry, tiling

An order 3 dipyramid can be split into two regular tetrahedra.

An order $n$ dipyramid can be split into $n$ isosceles tetrahedra.

[image]

A rhombic dodecahedron can be split into four rhombic hexahedra.

[image: rhombi]

A [4-scalenohedron](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/OctahedraConstructedFromEightIdenticalTriangles/) with edges of length $(\sqrt5, \sqrt8,\sqrt9)$ can be split into 4 congruent [isosceles tetrahedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsoscelesTetrahedron.html).

[image: 4-split scalenohedron]

A triakis tetrahedron with opposite corners $-(2,2,2)$ and $(3,3,3)$ can be cut into 4 isohedral triangular dipyramids.

[image: tetrakis]

A 4-scalenohedron with edges of length $(1, 1,\sqrt{12/7})$ can be split into 5 congruent isosceles tetrahedron.

[image: 5-split scalenohedron]

An isosceles tetrahedron with edges of length $(4, 2\sqrt3,2\sqrt3)$ can be split into 8 congruent copies of itself. 4 copies of this same tetrahedron makes an order 4 dipyramid, and it's also a space-filler.

[image: splitting tetrahedron]

A cube or trapezohedron can be split into 8 or more smaller cubes or trapezohedra.

These are all cases where an [isohedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isohedron.html) is split into isohedra.  Are there any other examples?

Comment: Do you require that the smaller isohedra be congruent to one another? If not, a regular tetrahedron can be split into tetrahedra and octahedra in many ways, as can the octahedron (I believe this still holds under an affine transformation taking the regular tetrahedron to an isosceles tetrahedron), and a trapezohedron of appropriate dimensions is the union of a regular octahedron and two regular tetrahedra.